# My data array has null values in chart.js. Is there a way to draw a line between the two segments to maintain visual progress?

Tags: frontend, chart.js

[image]

As shown in the screenshot, there are days where I have a null value... I would like to connect the dataset with a line regardless of a particular day being null. Is this possible in chart.js 2.x?

Answer (score 2):

You can set spangaps to true:

```js
const options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, null, 2, 3],
        borderColor: 'pink',
        fill: false,
        spanGaps: true
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [7, null, null, 8, 3, 7],
        borderColor: 'orange',
        fill: false,
        spanGaps: true
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {}
}

const ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change `spanGaps: true` to `spanGaps: false`.

https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/line.html#line-styling